# Translate JavaScript to VBScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have this HTML:

```html
<form name=tett>
    <input type=text name=tf value="testing prompt" size=15>
</form>
```

And this JavaScript:

```js
var df = prompt(" enter your name ");
document.tett.tf.value = df;
```

How can I do this in VBScript?

Comment: First probably learn VBScript.

Comment: My question is not how but *WHY* would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I try to lean to do this in V.b... I get some book but don't  tell me anything about this situation....

Comment: Also take a look at the DOM - that sort of variable access is pretty old.  You should be using document.getElementById and attaching an id to the input element.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this :

```
df = InputBox("enter your name");
form.tf.value = df;
```

.. but don't mind me asking: why do you want to do this in the first place?